# CSS file not recognized by inspect elements - mystery

Tags: css, element, inspect

The strangest thing is happening since a few days. Inspect element doesn't recognize a css file anymore (See attached image). Somehow the css file gets listed as an image.

I copied the content of this css file into another (working) css file to check if the problem was the content or something else like permissions. But then the working file didn't get recognized anymore either. So there's something really strange with the content.

Anybody got an idea?

[image]

http://sbx.mujjo.com/media/images/sc.png

Comment: Why do you have a stylesheet file in your `images` directory? And I don't know what you're referring to with "working file".

Comment: Probably URL address that is leading to css file is wrong.

Comment: It's not in the image directory, the screenshot is Chrome inspect elements, normally styles.css would display under 'Stylesheets' just like the other stylesheets also visible on the screenshot.

With working file I mean the css files that do show up correctly.

Comment: But it isn't, when I empty the css file it shows up correctly again. That's why it has to be something within the css file. But I can't imagine what, never seen this before..
 
!(http://sbx.mujjo.com/media/images/sc2.png)

Answer (score 1):

Solved! The following line caused this issue: **background: url('') top left no-repeat;** Apparently it's not allowed to leave the url blank. This confuses inspect elements at least! – Remy Nagelmaeker Dec 17 '11 at 18:04

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your putting your stylesheet in like so?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/styles.css" />
```

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://sbx.mujjo.com/skin/frontend/default/mujjo/css/styles.css" media="all">

Just like the other files, but somehow this one acts strange

Comment: Hmmm.. running it through the validator, line 1989 has `font-size:14fpx`, should be **px**. Line 4264, `.sitemap li a`, has property `align:left` which doesn't exist. Neither of these things should stop the css from loading, though...

Comment: Just want to mention about grouping selectors a bit. You've got a huge block of selectors that use the `:after` clearfix, which is great, but you could reduce that dramatically by just using something like a `clearfix` class, and apply that class to any elements that you want to fix, instead of targeting each one individually in your CSS.

Comment: Solved!

The following line caused this issue:

background: url('') top left no-repeat;

Apparently it's not allowed to leave the url blank. This confuses inspect elements at least!